# Powershell - Catch RPC Server Unavailable Error HRESULT: 0x800706BA

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I want to print custom error message in case of error

```
  Foreach ($server in $servers){
    
     Try{
           $admins = Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer $server
           $admins = $admins |? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Administrators"'}
           $admins = $admins |% { $_.partcomponent –match “.+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$” > $nul 
           $matches[1].trim('"') + “\” + $matches[2].trim('"') | Where-Object {$_ -like "$domain*"}}
    
     }
     catch [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException]
    {
       
            # You can inspect the error code to see what specific error we're dealing with 
        if($_.Exception.ErrorCode -like "*0x800706BA*")
        {
            # This is instead of the "RPC Server Unavailable" error
             Write-Verbose -Message ('{0} is unreachable' -f $computer) -Verbose 
        }
        else
        {
             Write-Warning $Error[0]
        }
       
    }
     
     # If any other type of Exception is thrown, execute this block
catch [System.Exception]
{
    Write-Error -Message "Some other exception that's nothing like the above examples"
}
     }
```

But i'm getting default error

Gwmi : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At line:4 char:18
$admins = Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer $server

```
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I want to print only names of servers where WMI command fails

I tried [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/618156/how-to-catch-exceptions-with-powershell) but no help

Tried also:

```
catch [Exception]
{
    if ($_.Exception.GetType().Name -like "*COMException*") {
         Write-Verbose -Message ('{0} is unreachable' -f $computer) -Verbose
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, had to specify  `-erroraction stop` on WMI command

Answer (score 0):

No to catch errors, you need to set ErrorAction to `SilentlyContinue`: `$admins = Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

Comment: How do you then report that the RPC server is unavailable for `$server`, since that is part of what the asker is trying to do?